# Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS every boot up need the following command to use wifi

Tags: 16.04, wireless, ralink

I am using asus x450cc . My os is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
my wifi info :

> ```
>    product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
>    vendor: Ralink corp.
> ```

Before using the following command...... the network manager (in the top most right )  only show Ethernet option ... No wifi option showing ....

> I need to run the following command to start my wifi working ..
>
> sudo ifconfig enp3s0f0  up
>
> sudo service network-manager restart
>
> sudo pm-suspend

Only after this command i can use my wifi .... (i need to do this in every boot it is so painful ....)

How can i fix my problem ..... Thank in advance :)